# Attaching category to items through OpenText content server Web services

Tags: web-services, metadata, categories, key-value-store, opentext

Has anyone ever implemented a solution of how to attach category to an item  through OpenText SOAP Web services?

I am trying to apply a category to an existing document/folder which is possible through the attribute group and metadata classes and then setting metadata on a node. Issue is that I am unable to set values in attributes.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve your
 question. Great questions tend to generate quicker, better answers from the community. - Please note: we are not a code-writing service.  You have to have a specific issue for us to help you with

Comment: Clutter removed. Spelling improved.

Comment: What version of OpenText are you using?